# How to read keyboard input, KeyChar, on FormLoad event in C#?

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, form-load

A key is pressed while starting up a winform program. I'd like to read this keyboard input during program startup process. How can I do that?

Comment: it is  a winform app ?

Comment: We need more information. First of all what are you working on? A console app, windows forms, wpf?

Answer (score 0):

Set **KeyPreview** of your Form to **True** and add your code in form's **KeyPress** or **KeyDown** event.